# Adding structure in array using new keyword similar to adding contract in another contract

Tags: arrays, inheritance, struct, solidity, new-operator

Below is the source code which I wrote to deploy one smart contract using another smart contract

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

import "./contractone.sol" ;

contract contracttwo
{
      contractone[] public deploy ;

    function contwo() public
    {  deploy.push(new contractone());  // able to add instance of data type i.e contractone using 'new'
    }
}
```

Now this contract worked. Similar to this I wrote another contract

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16 ;
 contract arr
 { people[] public person ;
    struct people
     {
         uint256 num ;
         string name ;
     }

      function plus() public
     {   
       person.push(new people()); // unable to new instance of data type i.e people using new       
     }
 }
```

In this contract when I tried to add new instance of people , I got the error

[Error upon trying 'new' keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxgNk.png)

It read that
:-

> TypeError: Identifier is not a contract.

I know first is case of contract and second is of structure.But the thing which I am trying to do is same i.e trying to new instance of  data of the array .Can anyone please tell me why new keyword  `new` is not working in second contract ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use "new" for second case.

```
function plus(uint _num, string memory _name) public {  
person.push(people(_num, _name));
}
```

Comment: But why `new` keyword does not work as I wrote in the programme.